# Calendar Program in java, i tried writing this code but is not working

Tags: java, calendar

I have to write a calendar in java, these are my guidelines...
Write a Java program that displays the calendar of any month of any year between 1900
and 2099.
Each output calendar must be displayed in the following form:

```
 January 1987
 Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                  1   2   3
  4   5   6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15  16  17
 18  19  20  21  22  23  24
 25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

If the input value is not a valid date, the user must be informed that date was not acceptable, and then be prompted again for another date. If more than three consecutive erroneous dates are given, the program must be terminated with an appropriate error message.

After displaying the calendar, the program must ask whether or not the user wants to enter another date (Do you want to continue?)

The user must answer either yes, no, y or n, in any combination of lower and upper case letters

Here's what I have so far.

```
package assignment.pkg2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2 {

  public static int getMonthNumber(String s) {
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jan")) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("feb")) {
      return 2;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("mar")) {
      return 3;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("apr")) {
      return 4;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("may")) {
      return 5;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jun")) {
      return 6;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jul")) {
      return 7;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("aug")) {
      return 8;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("sep")) {
      return 9;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("oct")) {
      return 10;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("nov")) {
      return 11;
    }
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("dec")) {
      return 12;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Not valid month!");
    }
    return 0;
  }

  public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    int month = 0;
    int s = getDaysIn(month, year);
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
  }

  public static int getDaysIn(int month, int year) {

    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        return 31;
      case 2:
        if (isLeapYear(month)) {
          return 29;
        } else {
          return 28;
        }
      case 3:
        return 31;
      case 4:
        return 30;
      case 5:
        return 31;
      case 6:
        return 30;
      case 7:
        return 31;
      case 8:
        return 31;
      case 9:
        return 30;
      case 10:
        return 31;
      case 11:
        return 30;
      case 12:
        return 31;
      default:
        return -1;
    }
  }

  public static String getMonthName(int month) {
    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        return "January";
      case 2:
        return "February";
      case 3:
        return "March";
      case 4:
        return "April";
      case 5:
        return "May";
      case 6:
        return "June";
      case 7:
        return "July";
      case 8:
        return "August";
      case 9:
        return "September";
      case 10:
        return "October";
      case 11:
        return "November";
      case 12:
        return "December";
      default:
        return "Invalid month.";
    }
  }

  public static int getStartDay(int month, int year) {
    int days = 0;

    for (int i = 1900; i < year; i++) {
      days = days + 365;
      if (isLeapYear(i)) {
        days = days + 1;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) {
      days = days + getDaysIn(month, year);
    }

    int startday = (days + 1) % 7 + 1;
    return startday;
  }

  public static void displayCalendar(int month, int year) {
    String monthName = getMonthName(month);
    int startDay = getStartDay(month, year);
    int monthDays = getDaysIn(month, year);
    System.out.println("   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat");

    int weekDay = startDay - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= startDay; i = i + 1) {
      System.out.print("    ");
    }

    for (int x = 1; x <= monthDays; x++) {
      weekDay = weekDay + 1;
      if (weekDay > 7) {
        System.out.println();
        weekDay = 1;
      }
      System.out.format("   %3d", x);
    }

    if (weekDay > 7) {
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Give the first three letters of a month and enter the year: ");
    String month, year;
    month = c.next();
    year = c.next();

    int yearno = Integer.parseInt(year);
    int monthno = getMonthNumber(month);

    displayCalendar(monthno, yearno);

  }
}
```

Comment: And which of the 13 requirements of your homework isn't working?

Comment: i tried to cover them all, but after i input the 3 letters and the year nothing happens

Comment: "Nothing happens" is not a useful description of behaviour, nor is "Not working". Does it crash? Do you have to kill the program? Where is it stuck? Does it only crash with all of the code you have posted, or can you remove a large amount of it (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Help us to help you.

Comment: when i said nothing happens is because that is what happens, it keeps running but i never get my calendar shown, so i have to end up closing that run

Comment: And please format your code well, especially if you're going to dump such a large amount of it.

Comment: That's not "nothing" happening, that is something like an infinite loop, a very slow computation, or it is blocked waiting for IO. What is it doing when you debug it?

Comment: What input do you give the program when you call it? I just gave it `oct 2015` and it prints a calendar (the days don't correspond with the dates that I have on my desktop's calendar though).

Comment: Dumping your entire HW prompt will more than likely deter people from answering. Try providing a description with what you've tried, what your input is, what the results were, how it differed from what you expected. Edit: Was able to run your code, not sure what you were expecting: run: Give the first three letters of a month  and enter the year: jan 2001
   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
             1     2     3     4     5     6
     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
    28    29    30    31

Comment: Give the first three letters of a month and enter the year: aug
1992
   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
                     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8     9    10    11
    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
    19    20    21    22    23    24    25
    26    27    28    29    30    31BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8UK-0iS8z9vQ1FXb2N2bmpXOTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I m sorry, i thought that providing with all the details could help others understand what i was trying to achieve.

Comment: my dates are one day off for example for this year

Comment: For this problem (only able to enter one date) the solution is simple. In the given algorithm is a loop, but you just read the first 2 inputs and print the calendar. Try to work on one thing at a time, for example start with the user input. Just promt the user for input in a loop, and print out what he entered. Next step: break the loop (and end the program) when the user types "exit". Now let the user enter 2 values and parse them, one a string the other a integer, etc... If you have problems at any of those small steps, you can create a new question here.

Comment: Or check if it is already answered (because it was asked by another person).

Comment: i will try thanks, i m just so confused....

Comment: No problem, if you start to learn something, you should not try to conquer the world in one "big" step. If you proceed "little" step by little step and get stuck, you exactly know what IS working and what is NOT (in your code), so you can ask more precise questions and get better/precise answers (or an answer at all).

Comment: can somebody tell me why are the numbers formatted like that on the first row?